# Catching a get/post in a controller and then validate

Tags: laravel-5

I have a controller that controls pages in the front end. On some pages there is a form and I would want to be able to post a form from that same page (for example /contact/form). So the form is generated in the same function as any regular page.

What I want is that the page function can catch if there is a post, validate the input fields and if not OK, show the error message on that same generated page.

I am wondering what is the best approach? Can I easily go about doing it something like below?

```
protected $rules = [
        'firstname' => ['required'],
        'lastname' => ['required'],
        'email' => ['required']
    ];

public function page($slug = null) {
    if(isset($_POST)) {
        $this->validate($request, $this->rules);
        // etc etc
    }
    $page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    // return view
}
```

Will this validate and if not show errors on that same 'generated' page?

Oh, and how do I get to change the routes.php to accept both post and get?

I now have it set as `any`:

```
Route::any('/{slug}', ['as' => 'pages.page', 'uses' => 'PagesController@page'])->where('slug', '[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+');
```

But cannot catch any POST using:

```
if (Request::isMethod('post')) {
    die('caught POST');
}
```

My full routes are:

```
Route::pattern('slug', '[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+');
if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $slug = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $slug = explode('?', $slug);
    $slug = explode('/', $slug[0]);
    if(!$slug[1]) {
        Route::any('/{slug}', ['as' => 'pages.page', 'uses' => 'PagesController@page'])->where('slug', 'home');
    } else {
        if($slug[1] != 'dashboard' && $slug[1] != 'migrate' && $slug[1] != 'form-submit') {
            if (in_array($slug[1], Page::lists('slug')) && !isset($slug[2])) {
                Route::any('/{slug}', ['as' => 'pages.page', 'uses' => 'PagesController@page'])->where('slug', '[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+');
                // if there is a second slug, go to PagesController@element
            } elseif (in_array($slug[2], ElementValue::where('element_field_id', 2)->lists('value_char'))) {
                Route::any('/{slug}', ['as' => 'pages.element', 'uses' => 'PagesController@element'])->where('slug', '[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\/]+');
            } else {
                Route::any('/{slug}', ['as' => 'pages.page', 'uses' => 'PagesController@page'])->where('slug', 'home');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use Laravel's `if(Request::method() == "POST")` function to determine if this is a `GET` or `POST` request, not `isset($_POST)`

Comment: Yes, I just realized and changed the question.

Comment: Right, but you're using `isMethod`, which isn't an available method on `Request` (to my knowledge anyway) http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_method

Comment: I have put `if(Request::method() == "POST") die('caught POST');` in my controller function, but it catches nothing and seems to handle it as GET

Comment: What does your form look like? Is it's method set as GET or POST? Also, if in doubt, run `dd(Request::method())` and that will tell you exactly what method it is catching.

Comment: Did the dd() and the answer is indeed `POST`. My form is like `<form method="POST" action="http://{{ $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">` so that seems ok. Can it be something in `any()` in the routes.php? Like that will always convert everything to GET?

Comment: I've never heard of that... But if that `dd()` statement is returning `POST` correctly, then the rest of your checks in that `page` function should work correctly. What, specifically, is going wrong?

Comment: `public function page($slug = null) {

  if(Request::method() == "POST") {
   die('caught POST');
  }` is ignored

Comment: But putting `dd(Request::method())` right before that line returns `POST` correct? That makes no sense...

Comment: No only in the view. In the controller it's ignored also

Comment: Do you even hit that `page()` function in your controller? Could be an issue with your routes (maybe the regex on the slug isn't working?) I really have no idea at this point...

Comment: Tim, I have added the full part of routes that handles this part in the question (for formatting purposes). The POST reaches the same page, only doesn't "see" if it's a POST and just handles it as a GET

Comment: If the first line in your `page()` function is a `dd()` that is getting ignored, it means you're not hitting that function...

Comment: Yes I am, as it's just continuing the rest of that page() function. Or should I just be simple and create a new FormController that only handles posts (so no gets) and when there is a validation error I use `if ($validator->fails()) { return Redirect::to('/page-where-i-am-from')->withErrors($validator); }`?

Comment: How could it possibly be continuing? `dd();` is short-hand for `die(var_dump());`... `die()` stops all execution of the page, so there is no way it would continue...

Comment: Dumb ass me... found my stupid mistake. I am using a slug[2] so I am at another function :$ It must be Friday. Thanx Tim for your patience

Comment: Haha no problem. Glad you were able to find the issue. Cheers!

Comment: Almost... Now the first part of the question. I will move this to an new thread